# Constructing a function with non-dense range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I would like to know if there is a general method to construct a function/operator with non-dense range. Specifically, some $L:X\rightarrow \mathscr{R}(L) \subset X$, where $X$ is a Banach space. What is the intuition behind such a process? An example would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can always construct a linear functional into $\mathbb{C}$ and then put $\mathbb{C}$ inside $\mathbb{C}^2$. So to avoid such trivial examples you might want to put more conditions

Comment: Thanks. I meant to say a function from say $\mathbb{C}$ to a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: even now one can construct a linear functional and then put $\mathbb{C}$ in $X$ as a one dimensional vector space

Comment: @TPP: By "function/operator", do you mean a linear function?  A linear function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$ is either always $0$ or surjective.

Comment: Thanks. That actually makes perfect sense.
@JonasMeyer What do you mean $0$ or surjective?

Comment: If $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is a linear map with respect to the complex vector space structure, it could be that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb C$, or not.  If not, the $f$ is surjective, meaning the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb C$, because if $x$ is an arbitrary complex number, and if $f(a)=b\neq 0$, then $f\left(\frac{x}{b}a\right)=x$.  Actually in this case $f(z) = \dfrac{b}{a}z$ for all $z$, determined by a $1$-by-$1$ matrix.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes. I do mean a linear function.

Comment: For $X\to X$, if $X$ is finite dimensional these are just the maps that aren't surjective, equivalent to those that are not invertible.  For $X$ an infinite dimensional Banach space, these are maps with range contained in a proper closed subspace $Y\subseteq X$, so you could consider for such a subspace, how can you get maps $L: X\to Y$?

Comment: If the range ir $\mathbb{R}$, I would use the floor or ceiling operator.

Comment: @martycohen: TPP has commented they mean linear functions.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you. I understand how this is done now.